# Why does the value of imadjust appears to be chopped off in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm supposed to show the relation of the input and output of the gamma correction algorithm as an assignment for my computer vision course. I'm using the `pout.tif` image the `imadjust` function and in Matlab to perform the operation. The code is pretty straight forward:

```
f = imread("pout.tif");
g = imadjust(f, stretchlim(f), []);

y = zeros([1 256]);

for c = 0:255
    v = g(f == c);
    if numel(v) ~= 0
        y(c+1) = v(1);
    end
end

plot(y);
```

The output is mostly what I expect. `imadjust` is mapping the pixels of `pout.tif` from roughly `[78 161]` to `[0 255]`, thus increasing the contrast. What I don't understand is why at some point `imadjust` begins to map all of the values to 255, from 161 to be precise.

I have provided an image of the mapping bellow, the tip of the graph seems to be chopped off. I expected the output to be a straight line, ranging from 78 to 161 on the x-axis and from 0 to 255 on the y-axis.

[image]

Comment: Refer to [stretchlim](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/stretchlim.html) documentation. `stretchlim` by default  uses the limit [0.01 0.99], saturating the upper 1% and the lower 1% of the histogram. It means that the example image has values higher than 161 that `imadjust` saturates those values.